# Inserting a date to database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am having a form with two textboxes where i am displaying the month calender like in any other online forms to select the date. The user selects the date. I want the user to select a date which is equal to or after the system date like tomorrow. I am comparing the dates and then trying to insert it into the database with two columns opening_date and closing dates. I don't even want the textbox to be left empty. I have the below code but isn't working out.

```
<?php
mysql_select_db("trials");
if(isset($_POST['next']))
{
    $odate=date("Y-m-d");//system date
    echo $odate;
    if(($_POST['date1']>$odate)||($_POST['date1']==$odate)&&($_POST['date1']!=""))
    {
    $s=mysql_query("insert into registration_date (opening_date, closing_date) values('$_POST[date1]','$_POST[date2]')");
    echo $s;
    if(mysql_query($s))
    {
        echo "successful";
    }
    else echo "error".mysql_error();
    }
    else
        echo "Enter A Valid Date";

}
?>
```

Comment: What is the exact error? Also you have a syntax error in your php code , please edit it.

Comment: Please note also, that mysql_* functions are deprecated. Take a look at PDO or mysqli. http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php or http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Comment: @Fracsi take a look at this comment when you need to disclaim against mysql_* :) http://brightmeup.info/comment.html

Answer (score 1):

You're also using mysql_query twice once on the set of `$s` and then your doing `mysql_query($s)` later on which is in effect doing `mysql_query(mysql_query("sql"))`

```
$s=mysql_query("insert into registration_date (opening_date, closing_date) values('$_POST[date1]','$_POST[date2]')");
    echo $s;
    if(mysql_query($s))
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
if(($_POST['date1']>$odate)||($_POST['date1]==$odate)&&($_POST['date1']!=""))
```

with this

```
if(($_POST['date1']>$odate)||($_POST['date1']==$odate)&&($_POST['date1']!=""))
```

You have missed one quote for date1 and also try like

```
$open_date = $_POST['date1'];
$close_date = $_POST['date2'];
$s=mysql_query("INSERT INTO registration_date (opening_date, closing_date)
                VALUES ('$open_date','$close_date')");
```

And try to avoid using mysql_* functions due to they are **depricated**.Instead use **mysqli**_* functions or **PDO** statements

Answer (score 0):

get system date with `function time()` like this: `$odate=time();` and trasform `$_POST[date]` in a number like this: `strtotime($_post[date])`. After this you can do this: `$_POST[date]>$odate`. in this way you will have two numbers to compare.